# Is FastCGI still a right answer?

Tags: fastcgi

FastCGI is old but it still seems like it must be the right answer in some cases.

It seems like the preferred deployment of Perl/Catalyst web applications is with FastCGI.

FastCGI was popular with Rails but seems to no longer be. (Why?)

The Java world doesn't seem to have anything to do with FastCGI. Is something like Tomcat way better than Apache+FastCGI?

Is choosing FastCGI still a good idea or just a lingering technology?

Ted

Comment: Although no definitive answer you might have some interest in http://plackperl.org

Answer (score 15):

Since it depends a lot on your setup and requirements, I'll let the "Is X still a right answer?" up to you.  However, by looking at different architectures, you can come up with a list of questions to ask to determine if it still is a right answer given specific circumstances.

#### Concerns of frequent interest

The questions you'll want to ask are usually related to security and flexibility.  For security, you'll want to follow the [principle of least privilege](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege).  For flexibility, you'll want to know if you can run multiple frameworks, multiple versions of the framework and how easily you can delegate work to other tasks.

#### Other concerns

For a simple web front-end to a database-backed application, not all of these questions are important.  You also need to keep in mind that some of the recommendations have *nothing* to do with what's outlined here.  Many web frameworks will recommend whatever architecture is easiest to setup with their framework.  They do this because it helps get new users trying out the framework with minimal fuss and without flooding the mailing list.  Also, the Java community tends to stick to a common denominator rather than take full advantage of the platform at hand, so they'll often recommend an all-Java solution.

### Popular architectures

#### Single process architectures

From a pure performance point of view, a single process (probably threaded) with an embedded framework probably gives most performance as it reduces most communication overhead between whatever receives the request and whatever produces a response.

**Security**: a single process must have *all* of the permissions required to perform *every* single task it is handed.  In simple applications, this might not be a problem.  However, its possible you might serve multiple services

**Flexibility**: probably can't run multiple version of the same framework (e.g. code for different parts of your website require different versions of Java, Rails, Python, etc.).  Moreover, changing your setup to serve some work on different machines becomes painful (less difficult when split up on virtual hosts).

#### Sub-process based architectures

Under the CGI model, you have to pay the price of spawning a new process for each request.  Even on UNIX machines where spawning a process is considered cheap, 600 requests a second will kill your server if you spawn a process for each.

**Security**: to spawn child processes under different user accounts, your gateway probably runs under quite high privileges.

**Flexibility**: additional flexibility for the multiple frameworks, multiple versions, multiple languages approach, but you're still stuck on the same machine.

#### Distributed architectures

The FastCGI/SCGI approach tried to solve the CGI process management problem in a clean way.  Just keep the process alive.  Have the gateway talk to that process to serve the request.

**Security**: Because the gateway doesn't spawn the processes that serve requests, the gateway can run with far less privileges enabled.  Actually, if it only serves as a gateway and doesn't do any work itself, it can run with hardly any privileges at all.

**Flexibility**: you get even better flexibility than the CGI model because you can forward the request to any machine on the network.

### Conclusion

I like FastCGI, because it gives me high flexibility at a price (i.e. request forwarded through socket) I can afford to pay.  It's not my full time job to administer systems.  I don't develop all the apps I hosts.  This means I look for the easiest solution for hosting whatever I try to host.  FastCGI popular enough to be supported by major web servers *and* popular web frameworks.  Adding another app usually just boils down to installing and mapping the desired URL to the application over FastCGI.